# C# best implementation so i can have a globally accessible class anywhere in the code but having the values specific to a request

Tags: c#, request, global-variables, global

**What is my ask**
I am uploading a word(docx) file , remove certain sensitive information from word file (like email, client name, phone number etc) and save it as a new word document.

**What I am doing:**
I have a .net core 6 application by which I upload a word(docx) file through an api endpoint.

I am using Open xml and Aspose word nuget packages to redact this sensitive information.

For each word file I upload I need to have a separate custom log information which lets me know what all information redacted specific to word file. For that only I created this Service and Class. As Different services (Open XML, Aspose Word) consume this logfile Class I need to have them on a global scope for that file upload operation.

**What I did**
Created a Transient service and used a class which I registered as Singleton, But it doesn't work as expected. When I have first file uploaded though the api endpoint am getting SanitizationLogModel with log information for the file, When I upload second file through api endpoint SanitizationLogModel already contains the first file log information

*.NetCore 6*

```
public class SanitizationLogService: ISanitizationLogService
{
        private SanitizationLogModel _sanitizedLogModel;

        public SanitizationLogService(SanitizationLogModel sanitizationLogModel)
        { 
             _sanitizedLogModel = sanitizationLogModel;
        }
        public SanitizationLogModel GetSanitizationLogModel()
        {
            return _sanitizedLogModel;
        }
        public void AddSanitizationLogEntity(SanitizationLogEntity entity)
        {
            _sanitizedLogModel.SanitizationLogs.Add(entity);
        }
}
```

and class

```
public class SanitizationLogModel
    {
        private string fileHeader;
        public string Submissionid { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Clientname { get; set; }
        public string Clientsector { get; set; }
        public string SanitizationLevels { get; set; }

        public string FileHeader { get;set; }
        public List<SanitizationLogEntity> SanitizationLogs { get; set; } = new List<SanitizationLogEntity>();

    }
```

And startup

```
services.AddTransient<ISanitizationLogService, SanitizationLogService>();
services.AddSingleton<SanitizationLogModel>();
```

Comment: Have you tried Scoped rather than Transient or Singleton?

Comment: That gives me some exception

Comment: Cannot resolve Helper.Interfaces.ISanitizationLogService' from root provider because it requires scoped service Models.SanitizationLogModel'

Comment: Which version of .net are you using?  Newer versions have built-in dependency-injected logging facilities that you can route however you want and will be much better suited to your use case

Comment: If you want something per request then you want to register it as Scoped `services.AddScoped<SanitizationLogModel>();`. The `SanitizationLogService` simply wraps the `SanitizationLogModel` so it technically does not matter if you register it as Transient or Scoped, but Scoped would save some instances.

Comment: BTW: Are we talking about ASP.NET? - I just guess because you are talking about requests

Answer (score 0):

The problem its that U are using the `SanitizationLogModel` in the DI process and is a singleton, so even if the `ISanitizationLogService` is Transient the resulting service its always gonna be the same. Remove the `SanitizationLogModel` from the DI and add it throw a method called at the start of the workflow.